# jQuery .submit Not working. Unable to get Value of Button using JQuery

Tags: php, html, jquery

jQuery Submit is not submitting value of button on `.submit();`

I just wanted to show a confirm bootstrap popup onclick of submit btn.

But using jQuery `.submit()` form element "Submit" value is empty.

HTML markup:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" rel="opsform" data-validate="true" role="form" name="frmsetsku" id="frmsetsku" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
//my input elements

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mr6 " name="Submit" id="btn-action-save" value="Save" type="submit" onclick="return submitSku();"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o bigger-115 ace-icon"></i>Save</button>

</form>
```

jQuery code:

```
function  submitSku() {
    event.preventDefault();
    bootbox.confirm("This Will Delete All Previous SKU and add Newly Entered SKUs ", function(result) {
        dialog = this;
        if(result) {
            document.getElementById("frmsetsku").submit();
        }
    });
}
```

PHP code:

```
$submit = initRequestValue('Submit');
//my initPostValue allows me to take post value by name
```

If I remove jQuery, the code is working fine but I add my jQuery submit value is not received.

Comment: Why do you need the form? You can use the HTML tag button only to trigger the operation. I could not see which PHP handles the submit?

Comment: Where are you initializing the `bootbox` object?

Comment: If you are using the `onclick` event to submit the form, then change the button type to `button`, instead of `submit`.

Answer (score 0):

The `<button>` element, having the "button" value in its type attribute, instructs the browser to provide a regular button which has no associated action. 
Its effects must be controlled by something else e.g. JavaScript onClick

Since you are using the Javascript `onClick` event to submit the form, change the button type to `button`.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" rel="opsform" data-validate="true" role="form" name="frmsetsku" id="frmsetsku" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mr6 " name="Submit" id="btn-action-save" value="Save" type="button" onclick="return submitSku();"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o bigger-115 ace-icon"></i>Save</button>
</form>
```